# Bind Go functions to web GUI using Rest API possible?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, go

I'm trying to make a web application with a front end and a back end, where as the go application is the backend, and the (HTML with Javascript) web-page is the front end.
A (seemingly) simple thing I want to do, is just press a button in the webgui, fetch this button-click in the go-app, and do something with it. Second thing I want to do is to update the web-page based on what i'm doing in the go-app.

To set this up I searched on the web and followed quite some interesting tutorials, with (more or less) the same approach: A RESTful API in GO, writing and reading data using the Json format. While I must say that this is interesting, I'm not succeeding to use it for my purpose. (Or maybe I'm just not smart enough to flex it to my purpose ;) ). Anyway I'm stuck.

What I have so far is (Go):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Person_t struct {
    name string `json:"name"`
    age  int    `json:"age"`
}

var Persons []Person_t

// !!! I need to do something here, but don't know what !!!
func TestFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    err := r.ParseForm()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/assets/", http.StatusFound)
}

// router functionality
func newRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    staticFileDirectory := http.Dir("./assets/")
    staticFileHandler := http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(staticFileDirectory))
    r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(staticFileHandler).Methods("GET")

    r.HandleFunc("/test", TestFunc).Methods("POST")

    return r
}

func webServer() {
    r := newRouter()
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func main() {

    /* some data */
    Persons = append(Persons, Person_t{name: "Piet", age: 22})
    Persons = append(Persons, Person_t{name: "Kees", age: 23})
    Persons = append(Persons, Person_t{name: "Klaas", age: 24})

    webServer()
}
```

and HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>test app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>test app</h1>
  <br/>
  <script>
    fetch("/test")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(sgList => {
        //Once we fetch the list, we iterate over it
        sgList.forEach(person => {
          //Create an input type dynamically.
          var btn = document.createbutton("BUTTON");
          btn.innerHTML = person.name;
          document.body.appendChild(btn);
        })
      })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Question:
Can I create as many buttons on the HTML webpage as I have available as data?
Can I make those buttons interact with my go-app?

If it not possible what I want, what would be the alternatives? (I would like to stick with GO if possible).

Comment: It is possible to make a go web API that can respond to different requests - yes. Why are you redirecting in your `TestFunc`, see this post on how to return JSON from a response https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/golang-response-snippets#json

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a couple issues with your go that you'll need to fix before you can get data back.

1. Your Person_t class attributes (name, age) need to start with an uppercase letter in order to be properly marshalled.  In go any variables that are lowercased are not exported, so a json marshalling package needs to be able to see it in order to read the interface.
2. You need to marshal and write the data to the responsewriter for the frontend to see it

This version should return json that you can use to integrate with a frontend component.

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "net/http"

  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Person_t struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

var Persons []Person_t

// !!! I need to do something here, but don't know what !!!
func TestFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  err := r.ParseForm()

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err))
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
  }

  jsData, err := json.Marshal(Persons)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err))
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
  }
  w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
  w.Write(jsData)
}

// router functionality
func newRouter() *mux.Router {
  r := mux.NewRouter()

  staticFileDirectory := http.Dir("./assets/")
  staticFileHandler := http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(staticFileDirectory))
  r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(staticFileHandler).Methods("GET")

  r.HandleFunc("/test", TestFunc).Methods("POST")

  return r
}

func webServer() {
  r := newRouter()
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func main() {

  /* some data */
  Persons = []Person_t{
    {Name: "Piet", Age: 22},
    {Name: "Kees", Age: 23},
    {Name: "Klaas", Age: 24},
  }

  webServer()
}
```

Note that you'll also probably need something more robust on the frontend to parse the response and dynamically build forms for each one.  I would recommend a simple [react application](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) that calls your /test endpoint in the constructor and iterate over the json response in the render, i.e.

```
getPersons() {
    fetch("/test")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(sgList => {
        this.state.persons = sgList
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {
        this.state.persons || null ? this.state.persons.map((person => (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Name: {person.name}
              <input type="text" value={person.age} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        ))) : null
      }
    );
  }
```